# zend framework 2 dose not access database from console application

Tags: php, database, zend-framework2, console-application

I am trying to run a controller from console, which is going to be used for a cron job. When I run the following Code Block in a http controller, it works perfectly. 
But when I use the same Code Block in a console controller and call it from Command Line, I get database error message:

"Statement could not be executed (3D000 - 1046 - No database selected"

I can't understand why it is not getting the database name and perhaps other parameters from config's local.php.
Any hint is appreciated

```
// CODE BLOCK IN CONTROLLER
$sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
$dbAdapter = $sm->get('Mymodule\Service\Db');
$actualDatabaseTableName = 'Operator';
$OperatorTableGateway = new TableGateway($actualDatabaseTableName,$dbAdapter);
$table = new OperatorTable($OperatorTableGateway);
$result = $table->getOperatorList();
var_dump($result->current());

And model class is
namespace Mydodule\Model;

use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;


class OperatorTable {

    protected $tableGateway;
    public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway) {
        $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
    }


    public function getOperatorList() {
        $select = new Select('Operator');
        $select->columns(array(
            'opId'=>'OperatorID',
            'ocode'=>'OperatorCode'
        ));

    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);  
    return $resultSet;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found the issue. It is all about Environment value.
The HTTPS request was getting EVN value from apache setting.
And the setting in application.config.php was
$env = getenv('APP_ENV') ?  : 'prod';

and since my prod.local.php was kind a empty, I did not work.

So what I learned is if you use Console application, the env value setting in apache will not kick in, or atleast in my case, and instead Console will use the setting in application.config.php